# Cannot import barba.js in sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, barbajs

This is my +layout.svelte file:

```
<script>
  import "../app.css";
  import barba from "@barba/core";
  barba.init();
</script>

<svelte:body data-barba="wrapper" />

<section
  class="bg-black  text-white"
  data-barba="container"
  data-barba-namespace="home"
>
  <slot />
</section>
```

The code results in a 500 internal error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')
    at +layout.svelte:4:2
```

Demo : [Bug Demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/headless-cloud-0rd3lx?file=%2Fpackage.json&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A21%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A21%7D%5D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `barba.init({});` inside `onMount`.

```html
<script>
import barba from "@barba/core";
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
onMount(() => {
    barba.init({
     // options
    })
})
</script>

<!-- Doesn't seem to work with svelte:body -->
<!-- It will report about wrapper -->

<main data-barba="wrapper">
    <section data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="home">
        <slot />
    </section>
</main>
```

I made some modifications to your demo [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wispy-wildflower-z6861e?file=%2Fsrc%2Froutes%2F%2Blayout.svelte&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A30%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A40%2C%22startColumn%22%3A30%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A40%7D%5D)